# The Android Studio isn't setting up for me

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio for the first time, and in those YouTube tutorial videos, the application works well. But, for some reason, in my Android Studio the preview won't load up, it shows the following message
`"Preview is unable until after a successful project sync."`

I've tried disabling the offline mode, removing the gradle folder from the parent directory, disabling firewall, setting up proxy (And it showed `Connection successful`, I use a proxy ethernet) and all the other solutions on the forum, even reinstalling the Studio again, but none works well for me.
I'm unable to use the Studio any further. I use, trying to use actually, Android Studio 3.5 on Windows 10.

the code entered in the content_main.xml is this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
 tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Hello World!"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The "build" view displays the following error.

```
 ERROR: Could not GET 
 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

When I click on the link given, a .pom file is downloaded.
When I click `Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`
the following error shows up.

```
ERROR: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

To sum it all up, this is the thing.
[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21HuH.png)

The build gradle(app) is as follows

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your `gradle` file which contains all of the imports?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Just search for the `build.gradle(app)` and paste it here

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS There you go.